# Groovy(XmlParser) Update attribute value using variable

Tags: groovy

I am trying to update the XML value using variable name but not successful.  Doing below code in soapUI. Not sure if that matters.

```
String books = '''
    <response version-api="2.0">
        <value>
            <books>
                <book available="20" id="1">
                    <title>Don Xijote</title>
                    <author id="1">Manuel De Cervantes</author>
                </book>
                <book available="14" id="2">
                    <title>Catcher in the Rye</title>
                   <author id="2">JD Salinger</author>
               </book>
               <book available="13" id="3">
                   <title>Alice in Wonderland</title>
                   <author id="3">Lewis Carroll</author>
               </book>
               <book available="5" id="4">
                   <title>Don Xijote</title>
                   <author id="4">Manuel De Cervantes</author>
               </book>
           </books>
       </value>
    </response>
'''

def response = new XmlParser().parseText(books)

def newavailable= "30"
def bookattribute = "available"

response.value.books.book[0].@bookattribute = newavailable
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you find my answer useful?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import groovy.xml.*

String books = '''
    <response version-api="2.0">
        <value>
            <books>
                <book available="20" id="1">
                    <title>Don Xijote</title>
                    <author id="1">Manuel De Cervantes</author>
                </book>
                <book available="14" id="2">
                    <title>Catcher in the Rye</title>
                   <author id="2">JD Salinger</author>
               </book>
               <book available="13" id="3">
                   <title>Alice in Wonderland</title>
                   <author id="3">Lewis Carroll</author>
               </book>
               <book available="5" id="4">
                   <title>Don Xijote</title>
                   <author id="4">Manuel De Cervantes</author>
               </book>
           </books>
       </value>
    </response>
'''

def response = new XmlParser().parseText(books)

def newavailable= "30";
def bookattribute = "available";

response.value.books.book[0].@"$bookattribute" = newavailable

XmlUtil.serialize(response)
```